# Laurent series of $\frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}$ around $\frac\pi2$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to do residue calculations for $\frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}$ but I'm running into problems with making the Laurent series.
The residue should be 2 [wolframalpha].
$\frac{1+(z-\frac\pi2)}{1-\sin(z-\frac\pi2)}$
$\frac{1+(z-\frac\pi2)}{1+\cos z}$
$\frac{1+(z-\frac\pi2)}{1+\sum_0\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^2n}$
$\frac{1+(z-\frac\pi2)}{2+\sum_1\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^2n}$
$\frac12\frac{1+(z-\frac\pi2)}{1+\sum_1\frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n)!}z^2n}$
$\frac12(1+(z-\frac\pi2))\sum_0(-1)^k(\sum_1\frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n)!}z^2n)^k$
But this is analytic, so the residue is 0.
What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want the power series around $+\frac\pi2,$ replace $(z-\frac\pi2)$ with  $(\frac\pi2+z)$ at the beginning of your calculation.

Comment: Why is that? I thought you shift the pole over the origin to calculate.

Comment: Precisely! If $z\to\frac\pi2$ then $z=\frac\pi2+h$ whith $h\to0.$

Comment: Yeah, it all works now.

Comment: You are welcome.